# Appium2 + iOS app : How to read system pop-up title, description and accept/dismiss button's text?

Tags: appium, ios, appium2

**Background** :
I am trying to handle system pop-up on iOS iPhone 15 using MacOS with M1.

**Problem** :
Previously using appium 1.x I was able to read, assert, handle system pop-up't title, description, accept & dismiss button and their text before performing action on it.

But after migrating to 2.x I can not read the title of ios system pop-up :(

Anyone has observe this kind of behavior and already aware about fix?